# socket.io - is JSON a must to send an object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a object in the frontend and I want to broadcast it to all connected clients. Can I send it as a mere object, the way I defined it? Or do I always have to stringyfy it as JSON object before sending?

my object:

```
var myBox = {
         x: 400,
         y: 700,
         w: 231,
         h: 199,
         c: "red",
         ....
         }
```

do I need stringify?

```
var myBox  = JSON.stringify({

            x: 400,
            y: 700,
            ...
        });
```

At the moment I send it like this and the msg is a JSON:

```
socket.emit('message', msg);
```

Comment: How are you "sending" it?

Comment: Who knows... you didn't give us nearly enough information to help you.

Comment: sorry I added some Infos. At the moment I send it like this: socket.emit('message', msg);

Comment: @poppel, Why not simply looking at the docs? http://socket.io/#how-to-use ... they have many examples where they pass objects as event's data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass the object to `emit` without stringifying it yourself. It will be sent as plaintext, but the client callback will be passed a parsed object.

In other words, doing this is fine:

```
var myBox = {     
    x: 400,
    y: 700,
    w: 231,
    h: 199,
    c: "red"
}

socket.emit('message', myBox);
```

When listening on the client, you don't need to worry about `JSON.parse`:

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {
    alert(data.x);
});
```

Comment: sorry I am a beginner, what do you mean by " the client callback will be passed a parsed object" ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to send an object you will need to serialize it to a string (or ArrayBuffer, to be exact) - some sequence of bits to go over the wire (under the hood of HTTP/WS).

Yet, that serialisation does not necessarily need to be `JSON.stringify`, it could be anything else as well.

From what I read in [their docs](https://npmjs.org/package/socket.io#readme), Socket.io has "*automatic JSON encoding/decoding*" so it will do call the `JSON.stringify` for you, accepting plain objects as arguments to `.emit` as well.

Comment: thanx, How would you then serialize the object above?

Comment: Although Bergi is correct that it doesn't *have* to be JSON... it really ought to be. JSON is a widely used notation for serializing objects with many libraries available for serializing and deserializing. No need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: You can serialize to any format provided the receiving end knows how to deserialize it.  If both sides are JavaScript, JSON really is the best option.

Comment: @poppel: The object above? JSON. But there might be times where other formats are more appropriate, you only want to send plain strings or something.

Comment: @Bergi, there are 2 contradictory answers... you are saying that you explicitely need to serialize the object while some others says that the serialization will automatically occur when passing an object. From what I can see on http://socket.io/#how-to-use, they are passing object references directly.

Comment: @plalx: Yeah, when I wrote the answer I didn't even knew the OP was using socket.io :-) However, currently I am confused myself by https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Messaging#json which contradicts that how-to…

Comment: @Bergi `emit` behaves slightly differently from `send`

Answer (score 1):

You can do a socket.emit with data from the object.

Like this:

```
socket.emit("message",{x:myBox.x,y:myBox.y, w:myBox.w, h:myBox.h, c:myBox.c});
```

or try:

```
socket.emit("message",myBox); //haven't tested it, but if it works, give plalx credit
```

Comment: Creating the object inline is completely unecessary and misleading. The way you are saying it suggests to the OP that the object needs to be defined inline, which is not the case.

Comment: It's not unnecessary or misleading. For the client-side receiving that info, if he wants to get the data attributes, it's as easy as:
socket.on("message", function(data){console.log(data.x);console.log(data.y);console.log(data.w);}); Easy to understand this way.

Comment: You are misunderstanding me. What I mean is that you can simply do `socket.emit('message', myBox);` There is no need for creating an inline object that replicates the structure of the first one.

Comment: I haven't tested it that way before, but you're probably right that it works.