# using socket.io to send JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to send 3 arguments to the server when a button is clicked.  I can get it to work with 1, but I get nothing when I have the code below set up to send all 3.

index.html

```
function ledOn(x,y,z){
  var data ={
      "ADDRESS":x
      "BANK":y
      "VALUE":z
      }
  socket.emit('led', data);
  }   

<input type="button" name="Output1" id="Output1/
" value="Out    put1" onmousedown="ledOn(0x20,0x12,0x40);/
" onmouseup="ledOn(0x20,0x12,0x00);">
```

i2csock123.js

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('led', function (data) {
console.log(data.ADDRESS);
console.log(data.BANK);
console.log(data.VALUE);

var VALUE = data.VALUE;
var ADDRESS = data.ADDRESS;
var BANK = data.BANK;
    b.i2cOpen(port, ADDRESS, {});
    b.i2cWriteBytes(port, BANK, [VALUE]);
  });
});
```

If I comment out 'BANK' & 'VALUE' in both sections & only use 1 argument in the ledOn() & button event, I get the correct value sent.  I don't know enough to know whether it is not sending or not being parsed correctly after being received by the server.

I'm referencing:
[socket.io - is JSON a must to send an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592908/socket-io-is-json-a-must-to-send-an-object)

```
var myBox = {     
x: 400,
y: 700,
w: 231,
h: 199,
c: "red"
}

socket.emit('message', myBox);
```

Comment: There should be a comma following each property of data (except the last). Eg: { "name" : "joe", "age" : "21" }

Comment: Please, in your browser open Developer Tools > Console, and check out the error. You have syntax error as @levi mentioned earlier.

Comment: Yep you both called it.  Thanks.